# What is the difference between Page Controller and mvc patterns?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns

What is the difference between Page Controller and mvc patterns? Can you provide links for understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller is one of the parts of the MVC pattern, so not sure your question makes too much sense. Unless you mean something else by Page controller?

Model - View - **Controller**

Answer (score 0):

A Page Controller is one part in the MVC pattern, the controller part.

Answer (score -1):

The Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern separates the modeling of the domain, the presentation, and the actions based on user input into three separate classes

Model. The model manages the behavior and data of the application domain, responds to requests for information about its state (usually from the view), and responds to instructions to change state (usually from the controller).

View. The view manages the display of information.

Controller. The controller interprets request and responses, informing the model and/or the view to change as appropriate.

References:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx
http://www.enode.com/x/markup/tutorial/mvc.html
```